# Show that the limit as x approaches zero for $\frac{2^{1/x} - 2^{-1/x}}{2^{1/x} + 2^{-1/x}}$ does not exist

Tags: calculus, limits

This problem was in one of the first chapters of a calculus text, so how would you go about solving this without applying L'Hôpital's rule?
I attempted factoring out $2^{1/x}$, as well as using u substitution for $2^{1/x}$.

By graphing, I can see that the left-side limit does not equal the right-side limit, but how else can I demonstrate this?

Comment: Try multiplying numerator and denominator by $2^{-1/x}$, provided $x\to 0+$.

Comment: Are you sure it's not $x\to 0^+$, though? As it is, it looks like the limit does not exist.

Comment: The limit does not exist

Comment: Sorry, yes, I'm remembering the wording incorrectly, but the question was phrased more like what you are saying - something along the lines of, show the limit does not exist by finding x→0- and x→0+.

Comment: $\lim\limits_{x\to 0^{-}}f(x)=-1$, $\lim\limits_{x\to 0^{+}}f(x)=1$

Comment: Calculate left and right limit then, find that they are not equal, and therefore the limit doesn't exist. (Technically you have already done this if you plotted this function)

Answer (score 1):

We can simplify the problem as follows:
$$\mathrm f(x) := \frac{2^{1/x}-2^{-1/x}}{2^{1/x}+2^{-1/x}} \equiv \frac{2^{2/x}-1}{2^{2/x}+1}
\equiv \frac{4^{1/x}-1}{4^{1/x}+1} \equiv \frac{1-4^{-1/x}}{1+4^{-1/x}}$$

All we need to do is consider the limits of $4^{1/x}$ and $4^{-1/x}$ as $x$ tends to zero.

- If $x<0$ and $x \to 0$ then $1/x \to - \infty$ meaning that $4^{1/x} \to 0$ and so $$\mathrm f(x) \equiv \frac{4^{1/x}-1}{4^{1/x}+1} \to \frac{0-1}{0+1} = -1$$
- If $x>0$ and $x \to 0$ then $-1/x \to -\infty$ meaning that  $4^{-1/x} \to 0$ and so $$\mathrm f(x) \equiv \frac{1-4^{-1/x}}{1+4^{-1/x}} \to \frac{1-0}{1+0} = 1$$

Since the left- and right-hand limits are different, the limit is not well-defined.

Answer (score 0):

Quite simple with *equivalents*:

$$2^{1/x}\pm2^{-1/x}\sim_{0^+} 2^{1/x},\enspace\text{hence}\quad\frac{2^{1/x}-2^{-1/x}}{2^{1/x}+2^{-1/x}}\sim_{0^+}\frac{2^{1/x}}{2^{1/x}}=1,$$
while
$$2^{1/x}\pm2^{-1/x}\sim_{0^-}\pm 2^{-1/x},\enspace\text{hence}\quad\frac{2^{1/x}-2^{-1/x}}{2^{1/x}+2^{-1/x}}\sim_{0^-}\frac{-2^{-1/x}}{2^{-1/x}}=-1.$$

Comment: Instead of using hence, you can use the $\therefore$ (therfore) operator.

Comment: Usually, I prefer to explain with ordinary language, rather than using more or less cryptic symbols. This is a test to see if beginners fully understand what they write.